# How to use two different database with relation in one asp.net mvc c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to use two different database with relation in one asp.net mvc c# application

Comment: You really need to be more specific and provide detail. There's no way that anybody is going to know what exactly you're asking here.

Comment: I am working with one mvc c# application which have two different database.if I make two different connection string. I got error Invalid object name 'dbo.Clients'... Is there any way that it can be act like one single database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the benefits of using **Entity Framework 4.0** is that it can handle data from multiple tables, or as in your case, multiple databases. Here is one [how-to article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/multiple-databases). There is somewhat of a learning curve, but many people like this approach, and Microsoft seems to be dedicated to it for the future.

Basically, using EF allows you to do the data mapping in its model, abstracting all the database and table joins from you. You get business objects with class and property names that you can understand, and that are easier to code against.

Answer (score 0):

static New table1DataContext Context1 = 
new table1DataContext ("ConnectionString1");
static table2DataContext  Context2 = new table2DataContext ("ConnectionString2");

//Linq statement in c#

var query = from a in table1DataContext.table1 from b in table2DataContext.table2 
            where a.ID == b.ID
            select new { a, b };